# create multiple excel sheets.xlsx based on each iteration

Tags: java

Prob : I have a method executeunixcommand that returns filename, the executionresults(ist iteration of that method), the unixcommandresult(ist iteration of that method). Once i get all the three values i(flename, executionresults,unixcommandresult) I want to create the excel workbook(xlsx) and create a sheet with some name+count (like unix1) and add data to that sheet. below is the method for the same.

once it completes adding the data for the first iteraton in sheet1(unix1), it will go back to the method and do the second iteration, bring the three result variables(filename,executionresults,unixcommandresult) and open the sheet and add the data in the second sheet of excel.

COuld you please tell me whats wrong in this code.

```
public int writeresultstoexcel(string filename, AttayList<String> executionresults, ArrayList<String> unixcommandresult)
{
File parsedfile = new File(fileName);
int count=0;
if(parsedfile.exists())
{
count=count++;
XSSFSheet resultsheetname = createSheet("FID- " +count);
}
else{
createexcel(filename);
XSSFSheet resultsheetname = createSheet("FID- " +count);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what errors you are getting, but from the code you provided, look at the first argument of the method writeresultstoexcel `filename` and the argument passed to the File class `fileName`. If these variable are same, they should match case.

If not, you should avoid using such confusing names.

Comment: Sorry. I m not getting any error. This is not creating the excel sheet as required. I get the message that excel file already existis and it doesnot go beyond that. please let me know if I am missing any info. Yes, I am pfirst converting the filename which is of string type to file type to check if the file exists or not in that particular path.